# I'd like to pass a Stylesheet to each page of the current session using XSS

Tags: javascript, css, session-cookies, xss

I'm a student in college.
We have a learning platform with a UI which gives you Windows Vista vibes.
I've found a way to inject Javascript in the homepage, but it's not possible on the other pages. I'm able to add a stylesheet, and effectively changing the look of my homepage, but would love to be able to do so too in the rest of the site. I've found ways to store values in your browser, using a LocalStorage obj or document.cookie, but this doesn't give me the ability to add js itself, which autoruns on load of the page. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks for helping out :))

Answer (score 0):

Great find!

It may be possible to turn the website into a SPA (Single Page Application) by intercepting the clicks on links (`<a>` elements with `href` attributes), using `history.pushState` to change the url without reloading and then loading the site manually using fetch/xhr and then insert the resulting body into the current page, however my personal recommendation would be to  use a userstyle browser extension and report the (self-)xss issue instead ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I'll definitely look into that. I am planning to report this issue, but not after being able to show my teacher how I used it to my advantage. It's always a good thing to show your dedication to their lessons ;) (in this case CyberSec and Webdesign)
I can't imagine they'd be mad that I revamped the UI hehe

The reason why I haven't used a extension is because I want it to be across everything, desktops, laptops and phones, instead of my own browser.